# sync ajax call doesn't fire beforesend event in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When i tried to call a ajax request with an option `async:false` it doesn't fire beforesend event in chrome. but it works fine in firefox.

Link of jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/gopotoya/2/edit

Comment: Please answer my question instead of editing. @Lipis

Answer (score 1):

Just go through this document  http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8819[1](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8819)